# checkout openni_ros for electric source installed

Tags: ros, xtion, openni-kinect, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a way to checkout the openni_ros package for a source installed electric ros version?

https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_ros/file/1f99fa033d83/

is the package I want.

I needed to install the electric version with the source to use the pcl-trunk.

Now I want to install the openni_ros package to run my asus xtion sensor.

Thanks Stefan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32293/checkout-openni_ros-for-electric-source-installed/) by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2012-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. On the linked website the revision number is displayed and then I did:

> hg clone -r 477 https://kforge.ros.org/openni/openni_ros

---

Originally posted by [Stefan](https://answers.ros.org/users/452/stefan/) with karma: 90 on 2012-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0